# multithreading consumer not producing same output as input using boost ringbuffer

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, circular-buffer

In my main program I am copying a string buffer into a boost ring buffer and then trying to consume that data in a created thread and writing to a file. In the main thread also I am writing the same data to a file but both input and output file is not matching.

I feel I am doing something incredibly stupid. Please help. Also, if there are any suggesting to improve the code that would really be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/circular_buffer.hpp>
#include <numeric>
#include <assert.h>
#include <thread> 
#include <mutex>
#include <chrono>
#include <time.h>
#include <cstdint>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::fstream;
using std::string;
#define SOME_FIXED_HARDCODED_NUMBER 40980

class MyClass {
        public:
        std::vector<int8_t> vec;
        public:
        MyClass(std::vector<int8_t> v){ vec = v; }
};

boost::circular_buffer<MyClass> cb(300);
int waiting = 1;
std::mutex my_mutex;
FILE *out_file;
FILE *in_file;

void foo() 
{ 
    while (waiting) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(my_mutex);
        if (!cb.size() || waiting == 0) {
            lock.unlock();
            continue;
        }
        if (!waiting)
            break;
        MyClass local_buf = cb.front();
        cb.pop_front();
        fwrite(local_buf.vec.data(), 1, local_buf.vec.size(), out_file);
    }
} 

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    out_file = fopen("output_data.raw", "w"); 
    in_file = fopen("input_data.raw", "w"); 
    std::thread th1(foo);
    char *buf = {"abc"};
    int counter = 0;

    std::vector<int8_t> mem;
    mem.insert(mem.end(), buf, buf + strlen(buf));
    while (counter < SOME_FIXED_HARDCODED_NUMBER)
    {
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(my_mutex); 
            /* if the circular buffer is full then wait for consumer to pull the data */
            while (cb.full()) {
                lock.unlock();
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(my_mutex); 
            }
            cb.push_front(MyClass(mem));
            fwrite(mem.data(), 1, mem.size(), in_file);
        }
        counter++;
    }
    waiting = 0;
    th1.join();
    fclose(out_file);
    fclose(in_file);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            while (cb.full()) {
                lock.unlock();
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
>>>             std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(my_mutex); 
            }
```

The marked `unique_lock` doesn't do anything as it will go out of scope immediately and unlock the mutex. Hence once you leave the loop the mutex is not locked and you have a racecondition. Instead, you should use `lock.lock()` to relock the mutex.

There is a few more bugs. You are not waiting for your `foo` thread to actually drain the buffer. It will stop as soon as the waiting flag is set by the main thread. Also, waiting should be an atomic.

Comment: but that doesn't solve the problem. Yes, it removes race condition but input and output file still differs.